# Sql error "Divide by zero error encountered" when the divisor is 0

Tags: sql

I have an error coming up "Divide by zero error encountered." in SQL Server 2005. I understand that i have few rows that are are getting divided by Zero that results in this error. So i was wondering if can eliminate this error when the divisor is zero. if the divisor is 0, it should return 0. How can i do that?

```
sum(isnull(cast(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10, 2)), 0)) / sum(isnull(cast(S.AmountSold as numeric(10, 2)), 0))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use `case` to detect the 0 value and not run the division.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CASE statement:

```
CASE WHEN SUM(ISNULL(CAST(S.AmountSold as numeric(10, 2)), 0) = 0
        THEN 0
      ELSE 
        SUM(ISNULL(CAST(S.S_AmountCollected as numeric(10, 2)), 0)) 
           / 
        SUM(ISNULL(CAST(S.AmountSold as numeric(10, 2)), 0))
     END
```

Comment: I believe he has an error when the value is 0, not null, but the solution you show will still work with a small change

Comment: yeah.. it was hard to untangle his one-liner.. :)

Comment: CASE works great! Thank you Miky! :-)

Comment: The page wont let me accept an answer for 10 minutes after the post. Hmmm :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can not eliminate this error as an integer divided by 0 has undefined value. You will have to add an explicit check to have the behavior you expect.